# Как узнать сколько памяти отжирает преложение в текущий момент (программно)

Tags: c#

Необходим код, который возвращает в байтах занимаемую память текущего приложения, как в диспетчере задач.

Комментарии ниже приводят к следующему результату:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `(int)System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64` вроде бы в байтах возвращает значение

Comment: вернул 110870528, в диспетчере 46Мб

Comment: Результат может быть закэширован, поэтому перед взятием значения надо еще его обновить `Process myProcess = Process.Start("NotePad.exe"); 

do
                {
                    if (!myProcess.HasExited)
                    {
myProcess.Refresh(); Console.WriteLine("  physical memory usage: {0}", myProcess.WorkingSet64);  }
                }
                while (!myProcess.WaitForExit(1000));`

Comment: К сожалению тот же результат

Comment: Постоянно добавляет 40Мб. Не критично, мне просто нужно следить за ростом памяти. Но осадочек еть...

Comment: Ммм. может это показывается частный набор памяти?... там же есть расширенная статистика у диспетчера...... просто есть Рабочий набор , частный набор........ Рабочий набор — как раз количество памяти, используемое процессом в настоящий момент времени......... Частный набор и общий набор — под общим объемом подразумевается тот, который может быть освобожден для другого процесса, если ему станет не хватать RAM. Частный набор — память, строго отведенная конкретному процессу и которая не будет передана другому......WorkingSet64 - это как раз рабочий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужно именно значение, показываемое в Task Manager, то его можно вычитать из счетчиков производительности:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string prcName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
        var counter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set - Private", prcName);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}K", counter.RawValue / 1024);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

На самом деле Working Set - Private - это не совсем "количество памяти, выделенное процессу". Сам по себе Working Set - это та часть виртуальной памяти, к которой процесс обращался недавно, и которой еще соответствует физическая память. А Working Set - Private - это неразделяемая часть Working Set.

Т.е. реальному потреблению памяти этот показатель имеет очень косвенное отношение, т.к. зависит не только от выделения памяти в программе, но и от того, как давно программа к ней обращалась, и от общего состояния памяти в системе.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно